# How to create a box around text and formulas via tikz and minipages, but it doesn't break over pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, box

I'd like to create a box `\mybox` with `tikz`, to highlight environments, mathematical
formulas etc. Below is a MWE based on `minipage` (to have the flexibility to put
pretty much anything in the box). It works well as long as the content
of the box doesn't exceed the current page (see `\mybox{\blindtext[2]}`). If the
content of the box exceeds the current page (see `\mybox{\blindtext[6]}`), then
it doesn't properly break the page. This is of course because of the `minipage`.
Is there a more flexible way to define `\mybox`, so that it properly breaks over
pages? (in particular, I'd like to keep using `tikz` for the box's background as it allows for great
customization of the shape of the box).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mybox}[2][\textwidth+4.8mm]{% width (optional), content
  \par\noindent\hspace{-2.4mm}% shift to the left to vertically align text
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mydrawstyle/.style={rounded corners}]%
    \node(mynode)[rounded corners, inner sep=2.4mm, fill=black!12]{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{#1-4.8mm}%
      #2
      \end{minipage}%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \par%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\mybox{\blindtext[6]}% \blindtext[2] works, but \blindtext[6] breaks the page right away (and then doesn't fully fit on the next)
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Working with `tcolorbox`, I obtain:

```
\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{text width=\textwidth, breakable, skin=enhanced,
                     arc=3mm, left=2mm, top=2mm, right=2mm, bottom=2mm, boxsep=0mm,
                     colback=black!12, colframe=black!12}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{mybox}
  \blindtext[3]
  \clearpage
  \blindtext[3]
\end{mybox}
```

It is unclear (yet) how to indent the box (move a bit to the left) to vertically align its content with that of the adjacent text (as it was for the above MWE).

Comment: Minipage can't be break between pages. For this you should use `tcolorbox` package and option `breakable`. Se example in the package documentation , page 390-391.

Comment: On the same way as with minipage.  Increase width of box accordingly.

Comment: With that you can control the width of the text. Paired with left/right etc. you can also get the desired distance between the frame of the box and its content. However, I don't see how the whole box could then be indented so that the text in the box is vertically aligned with the text before the box.

Comment: Do you try to define a breakable box? If yes, and it can be break between packages, than you include it in your new command as before minipage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `tcolorbox` inside a node of the `tikzpicture` also failed, but I finally found the option `enlarge left` of `tcolorbox` and so the following solved the problem for me:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{text width=\textwidth, breakable, skin=enhanced,
  arc=3mm, left=2mm, top=2mm, right=2mm, bottom=2mm, boxsep=0mm,
  enlarge left by=-2mm, colback=black!12, colframe=black!12}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{mybox}
  \blindtext[6]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```